# "Proportional to" - but nonlinear.

Tags: functions, terminology

If $A$ is proportional to $B$, then it means that $A$ varies with $B$ linearly (we're just not specifying the linear constant). Is there a similar notion for the case that $A$ increases as $B$ increases, but in the case that this relationship isn't necessarily linear? I'm looking for something like "$A$ is ______ to $B$".

Comment: "correlated positively" comes to mind, from statistics

Comment: I leave this as a comment since i'm not sure what you're really looking for?

Comment: "Positively correlated" is definitely a weaker condition.  It implies that on average they are increasing functions of each other, but only on average. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Good point

Comment: You said it yourself--I think "A varies with B" might work fine, depending on the context. Or, if A and B are continuous functions, $sgn(A') = sgn(B')$.

Comment: "$A$ varies with $B$" doesn't do it.  $A$ could vary with $B$ without being monotone. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

"$A$ is an increasing function of $B$" or "$A$ and be are increasing functions of each other" or "$A$ increases with $B$".